# How to transform hardcoded strings to polylang suitable translatable stings in WordPress private theme?

Tags: php, string, wordpress, hardcoded

I'm using "Polylang" plugin for multilingual site. So, there is some points not suitable for translating strings. Some of theme I could change for become suitable. However, for some others, I couldn't.

Here is the codes below.

template-contacts.php

Original code

```
if ( $message_btn ) : ?>
        <div id="contacts-modal" class="reveal-modal">
             <h1 class="entry-header"><?php _e( 'Send message', 'fluxus' ); ?></h1>
             <div class="modal-contents"></div>
             <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
        </div><?php
    endif;
```

I've changes code as

```
if ( $message_btn ) : ?>
    <div id="contacts-modal" class="reveal-modal">
         <h1 class="entry-header"><?php pll_e( 'Send message' ); ?></h1>
         <div class="modal-contents"></div>
         <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div><?php
endif;
```

This works for regarding part. However, there is send message and view map buttons, and also "Use arrow %s keys for navigation" text in the footer. I couln't success to change, solve this parts. Here is the code:

```
if ( $has_map ) {
    $view_btn = '<a id="view-map" href="#" class="button icon-location">' . __( 'View map', 'fluxus' ) . '</a>';
} else {
    $view_btn = '';
}

/**
 * Show Send Message button only if there is a [contact-form-7] short tag
 * in the content.
 */
if ( preg_match('/\[contact\-form\-7.+?\]/is', $post->post_content) ) {
    $message_btn = '<a id="send-message" href="#" class="button icon-paper-plane">' . __( 'Send message', 'fluxus' ) . '</a>';
} else {
    $message_btn = '';
}

?>
```

How can I make changes on the part above?

Answer (score 2):

try to change `__( 'View map', 'fluxus' )` to `pll__( 'View map' )`

and `__( 'Send message', 'fluxus' )` to `pll__( 'Send message' )`

of course 'view map' and 'send message' need to be previously registered

`pll_e(` or `_e(` echo the string and `__(` or`pll_(` return the string.